# Issues intercepting xhr requests to assets with Android Webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-assets

quick question here, would appreciate the help.

I am using a WebView on one of my Android apps and am making XHR requests to android_assets files using the file:/// scheme, those requests are all working fine, however I encountered some issues when trying to intercept those.

I attempted that using both shouldOverrideUrlLoading and shouldInterceptRequest (using both the deprecated version and the latest one), in both attempts those callbacks were called by Android with the request, but upon looking on the URL passed in both of those requests.

Instead of getting my expected resource path with the file:/// scheme and my requested file path, I received something along the lines of "blob:file:///{GUID}" as the URL (where GUID appears to be an actual GUID).

Am I doing something wrong in my attempt to view those URL's? Is it possible to retrieve the actual file path in the assets folder from that GUID? When attempting to intercept HTTP requests being made I am able to see the real URL.
I thought it had something to do with the settings, but I have enabled every option I was able to find relating to local file access from WebViews.

Please note, I am not asking how to intercept requests using WebView as that is already clear to me, I am merely asking about this specific situation in hopes someone has encountered that already, thank you very much for any help you can provide